# XSL apply templates with sorting and conditon

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to apply XSLT 1.0 to the XML. Two examples of my XML are below, there can be many Financial elements and they are unordered.

1.

```
<Financials>    
    <Financial Type="Full">
        <Year>2013</Year>
    </Financial>
    <Financial Type="Full">
        <Year>2012</Year>
    </Financial>
    <Financial Type="Full">
        <Year>2011</Year>
    </Financial>
    <Financial Type="Interim">
        <Year>2014</Year>
    </Financial>
    ...
</Financials>
```

or

2.

```
<Financials>
    <Financial Type="Full">
        <Year>2014</Year>
    </Financial>   
    <Financial Type="Full">
        <Year>2012</Year>
    </Financial>
    <Financial Type="Full">
        <Year>2011</Year>
    </Financial>
    <Financial Type="Interim">
        <Year>2013</Year>
    </Financial>
    ...
</Financials>
```

I need to map this into exactly 3 `<OutputFinancial>` elements, ordered by Year from most recent. But also the condition is:

- if most recent element is Type='Interim' then map this element and also two Full
  type elements.
- otherwise map three Full type elements.

So output would be following:

1.

```
<OutputFinancials>
    <OutputFinancial>
        <Year>2014</Year>
    </OutputFinancial>
    <OutputFinancial>
        <Year>2013</Year>
    </OutputFinancial>
    <OutputFinancial>
        <Year>2012</Year>
    </OutputFinancial>
</OutputFinancials>
```

2.

```
<OutputFinancials>
    <OutputFinancial>
        <Year>2014</Year>
    </OutputFinancial>
    <OutputFinancial>
        <Year>2012</Year>
    </OutputFinancial>
    <OutputFinancial>
        <Year>2011</Year>
    </OutputFinancial>
</OutputFinancials>
```

I started with:

```
<OutputFinancials>
    <xsl:for-each select="Financial">
        <xsl:sort select="Year" data-type="number" order="descending" />
        <xsl:if test="position()=1 and @Type='Interim') or ??? " />
        <OutputFinancial>
            <Year><xsl:value-of select="Year" /></Year>
        </OutputFinancial>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</OutputFinancials>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the same template with filtered nodes depending on your conditions. The first one below calls the template for any kind of `Financial` node, when `Interim` is the most recent one. If that condition is false, it will filter only the `@Type=Full` nodes and call the same template.

```
<xsl:template match="Financials">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Financial[@Type='Interim'][not(Year &lt; ../Financial/Year)]">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Financial">
                <xsl:sort select="Year" data-type="number" order="descending" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Financial[@Type='Full']">
                <xsl:sort select="Year" data-type="number" order="descending" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

In the template, since the nodes are ordered, you can select only the first three:

```
<xsl:template match="Financial">
    <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= 3">
        <OutputFinancial>
            <Year><xsl:value-of select="Year" /></Year>
        </OutputFinancial>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

So the first one will include three nodes, which are the most recent `Interim` and two others (with no condition tested). The second will include only the most recent `Full` nodes.

Comment: I cant check now but wont position() in the second template be always = 1?

Comment: ok, position() works but can you please explain how 'when Interim is the most recent one.' works?

Comment: The size of the node-set that matches `Financial` will be determined by the amount of nodes filtered by the calling templates. In the `otherwise` clause, it's called with all `Financial` nodes that have `@Type='Full'`, and each will have a different `position()`. So the template selects the first three. In the `when`, at most one node is selected in the set, so it will call the template with a node-set of size 1, and yes, in that case, `position()` will be 1. But the test is necessary because the template is reused.

Comment: `Year < ../Financial/Year` returns true only if the current `Year` is less than all the other `Year` elements in the `Financial` sibling nodes. It will return a collection of all the years except for the last one (the most recent). Using `not()` inverts that, and thus selects the most recent year.

Comment: Thanks, for simplify the example I typed Year in YYYY format but in fact its 2012-12-31T00:00:00. In this case 'Year < ../Financial/Year' does not seem to work?

Comment: You are right, because it's no actually a Year, then, but an ISO date. And that invalidates the whole example. You can still use it if you extract the year from each date (assuming that what you are *really* interested in is the year): `substring(Year,1,4)) &lt; substring(../Financial/Year,1,4)` which will extract the 4 year digits from the date to compare them. You will have do that in the Year that is used in the `sort` too, *or* order them as strings: `data-type="string"`.